# How to compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\:\frac{\exp(-ax^2+bx)}{x+1}\:\text{ for }\: a>0, b\in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

As the title says I am trying to compute the integral  $I=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\:\frac{\exp(-ax^2+bx)}{x+1}$ where $a>0$ and $b$ is a complex number. For the special case of $b=-2a$, we have $I=-\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\exp(a)\:\text{Ei}(-a)$ (where $\text{Ei}$ is the [Exponential Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) function). However, for the general complex values of $b$ I am not sure how to compute this integral in terms of some known function.

Comment: if you're interested in small values of a, why not perform an expansion wrt to this parameter and integrate sufficiently many terms? The resulting integrals can be expressed in terms of incomplete Gammafunctions...

Answer (score 1):

Using

$${{\rm e}^{bx}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( bx \right) ^{n}}{n
!}}
$$

and Maple I am obtaining the following result is terms of  Meijer G function

$$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-a{x}^{2}+bx}}}{x+1}}{dx}=\sum 
_{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{b}^{n}
G^{3, 2}_{2, 3}\left(a\, \Big\vert\,^{1/2, 1}_{1, 1/2, n/2+1/2}\right)
}{2n!\,\pi \,{a}^{n/2+1/2}}}
$$

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want an answer as a power series in b. Actually I am trying to see the behaviour of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\: \frac{\exp(-a(x+1)^2+2\pi i k x)}{x+1}$ for small values of $a$. Expanding in $b=-2a+2\pi i k$ doesn't seem helpful in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$I(b)=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-ax^2+bx}}{x+1}dx$

$\dfrac{dI(b)}{db}=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{xe^{-ax^2+bx}}{x+1}dx$

$\therefore\dfrac{dI(b)}{db}+I(b)=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2+bx}~dx$

$=\int_0^\infty e^{-a\left(x^2+\frac{bx}{a}\right)}~dx$

$=\int_0^\infty e^{-a\left(x^2+\frac{bx}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)}~dx$

$=e^\frac{b^2}{4a}\int_0^\infty e^{-a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2}~dx$

$=e^\frac{b^2}{4a}\int_\frac{b}{2a}^\infty e^{-ax^2}~dx$

$=e^\frac{b^2}{4a}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}~dx-\int_0^\frac{b}{2a}e^{-ax^2}~dx\right)$

$=e^\frac{b^2}{4a}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{a}}-\int_0^\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}e^{-x^2}~d\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt a}\right)\right)$

$=e^\frac{b^2}{4a}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{a}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt a}\int_0^\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}e^{-x^2}~dx\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{a}}e^\frac{b^2}{4a}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{b^{2n+1}n!}{2a^{n+1}(2n+1)!}$ (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function)

$e^bI(b)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{a}}\int e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}+b}~db-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{b^{2n+1}e^bn!}{2a^{n+1}(2n+1)!}db$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{a}}\int e^{\frac{1}{4a}(b^2+4ab)}~db-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{b^{2n+1}e^bn!}{2a^{n+1}(2n+1)!}db$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{a}}\int e^{\frac{1}{4a}(b^2+4ab+4a^2-4a^2)}~db-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{b^{2n+1}e^bn!}{2a^{n+1}(2n+1)!}db$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{a}}e^{-a}\int e^\frac{(b+2a)^2}{4a}~db-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{b^{2n+1}e^bn!}{2a^{n+1}(2n+1)!}db$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sqrt\pi e^{-a}(b+2a)^{2n}}{2^{2n+1}a^{n+\frac{1}{2}}n!}db-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{b^{2n+1}e^bn!}{2a^{n+1}(2n+1)!}db$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sqrt\pi e^{-a}(b+2a)^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}a^{n+\frac{1}{2}}n!(2n+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n+1}\dfrac{(-1)^kb^ke^bn!}{2a^{n+1}k!}+C$ (can be obtained from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions)

$I(b)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sqrt\pi e^{-a-b}(b+2a)^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}a^{n+\frac{1}{2}}n!(2n+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n+1}\dfrac{(-1)^kb^kn!}{2a^{n+1}k!}+Ce^{-b}$